# how to add a space in lines after specific character linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have some text files as below. I would like to add a space character in all lines after all comma character. How can I do in linux?

```
J12_1xtc,  10, 10,  1,-10.0600, 43.7866, -1.4100,  51,19
CP0_1xtc,  10,  9,  1,-11.3600, 44.3436, -0.8000,  44, 6
TS2_1xtc,  10, 10,  1,-11.1200, 44.3918, -3.0000,  61,14
BNR_1xtc,  10, 10,  1,-11.1500, 44.4234, -3.9000,  96,22
VAX_1xtc,  10, 10,  1,-10.9400, 44.7986, -3.8300, 137,27
ABC_1xtc,  10, 10,  1,-13.2500, 45.0794, -2.3300,  82,30
KAN_1xtc,  10, 10,  1,-14.7400, 46.2663, -0.3800,  48,17
6M0_1xtc,  10, 10,  1,-16.0100, 46.5524,-11.5400,  48,16
X2A_1xtc,  10, 10,  1,-14.6100, 46.7213, -1.2500,  72,15
1P2_1xtc,  10,  4,  5,-11.8300, 46.7528, -0.7300, 100, 2
6VQ_1xtc,  10, 10,  1,-10.2200, 46.8703, -0.5800,  71,24
1P1_1xtc,  10,  5,  2,-12.0200, 46.9872, -0.0700, 100, 2
HI1_1xtc,  10, 10,  1,-10.1800, 47.6840, -2.5100,  52,17
I21_1xtc,  10, 10,  1,-10.7500, 48.6488, -0.7200,  42, 3
2KC_1xtc,  10, 10,  1,-10.1000, 48.9203, -0.3100,  31, 6
51H_1xtc,  10, 10,  1,-14.7900, 48.9305, -0.1500,  73,25
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add space:

```
sed -i 's/,/, /g' fname.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, also if I want to add a space character after only fourth comma character, how can I do this?

Comment: @Sulejmani, use `s/,/, /4` to replace only 4th occurrence of pattern... with GNU sed, you can do `s/,/, /4g` to replace all occurrences from 4th match onwards